# Когда следует использовать семафор в многопоточном программировании?

Tags: java

Какие достоинства и недостатки есть у семафора? Когда следует использовать именно его? Если семафор так хорош, то почему бы не использовать его все время?

Comment: Это вопрос с билета?

Comment: нет, с собеседования уже прошедшего?

Comment: И как Вы сами ответили?

Comment: "ну, семафор - это средство синхронизации, которое позволяет нескольким потокам использовать один ресурс одновременно, это как мутекс только со счетчиком потоков"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Какие достоинства и недостатки есть у семафора?

Тут так одним словом не отпишешь. Недостатки - он не бесплатен (см. ниже).

> Когда следует использовать именно его? 
> когда два и больше потока пытаются получить доступ к одному ресурсу, который может использоваться только одним потоком одновременно.
> Примеры:

- запись в файл лога
- запись в сокет/чтение с сокета

Классическая задача - [Проблема обедающих философов](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B2).

> Если семафор так хорош, то почему бы не использовать его все время?

семафор не бесплатный. То есть, его использование занимает отбирает процессорное время. В однопоточных программах целесообразность использование семафора под вопросом.

Comment: @KoVadim, мне кажется ТС-а просили сопоставить mutex (без счетчика) с семафором.

Даже ессли нет, то все равно эти знания могут быть ему полезны.

Comment: предлагаю TC написать семафор на базе мютекса или чего-либо другого (может на обычных int напишет:) ) и разобраться как тестить (та же задача о философах может быть хорошим тестом. Можно понаставлять assert'ов и запустить на день-другой)